# Set address as constant in Vyper

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, vyper

The Vyper docs say that one can define a constant like this:

```
TOTAL_SUPPLY: constant(uint256) = 10000000
```

but what about defining an constant with type `address` ?

This doesn't compile:

```
CONTRACT_ADDRESS: constant(address) = '0x251C4A81963B45b86330F5483A22D041b455d2f0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this compiles successfully:

```
CONTRACT_ADDRESS: constant(address) = 0x251C4A81963B45b86330F5483A22D041b455d2f0
```

The address must be checksummed first.

For example in python this can be done like this:

`web3.toChecksumAddress('0x251C4A81963B45b86330F5483A22D041b455d2f0')`